# Can the estimated time of access times for distributed keyvalue stores be below 1ms?

Tags: performance, nosql

I'm digging through various Redis/Ceph/Elliptics benchmark to determine, whenever its theoretically possible to reach (very optimistic) request completion time below milliseconds in a non-SSD non-million worth-of-SAS-disks environment.

It is known that for localhost installations, random read performance for Elliptics large dataset is around 3.5ms/item, and almost same time is [officially](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks) given for Redis.

(Note: network latency is ignored for this question).

Is there a known K-V store with higher confirmed performance?

Comment: Disks only spin so fast. There's a certain minimum latency associated with having to get the data.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz but there is RAM..

Comment: If 100% of your data fits in RAM, then fine. But any time a request needs data not in RAM, you have that disk latency. No matter what the software does, you have that inherent limit.